# What is the most efficient solution for reading properties from a properties file by prefix?

Tags: java

What is the most efficient (in terms of time complexity) solution for reading properties from a properties file by prefix?

For example, if the properties file looks like this -

```
prefix1.prop1=val1
prefix1.prop2=val2
prefix2.prop3=val3
prefix2.prop4=val4
```

I am looking a for a method which when called like this -   `getPropertiesByPrefix("prefix1")` should return the following list :

```
["prefix1.prop1", "prefix1.prop2"]
```

I can see 2 options -

1. On every `getPropertiesByPrefix` call, read all the properties one by one and get the props starting with prefix.
2. Read properties once and build a trie and then `getPropertiesByPrefix` uses the trie.

The 2nd option seems to be the more efficient way to go. Are there any existing implementations/third-party libs for these? Or a third option?

Comment: How large is the property file you have in mind? I've never seen one where algorithmic performance would matter in the slightest. And when it's so big that it does, it's likely that I/O performance of reading from disk is so bad that any kind of terrible (like a list) datastructure would win. At least as long as you have enough memory. A simple `TreeMap` should btw also work as rather quick in-memory store

Comment: The number would be in 100s I am envisioning. Thing is that I would be accessing it by prefix on every single request. So having an O(n) lookup seems expensive.

Comment: The reading and loading of the property file is already there by the way. So I have to work with the util.Properties object.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do it using regex? Maybe the trie is more efficient but It takes space. Do you need the trie in your heap for the whole runtime of the program?

Answer (score 1):

The analysis are simple.

Say you have `properties` of n number of keys, then a loop that does `key.startsWith(prefix)` would run in `O(m*n)`time, m being the size of the prefix.

On the other hand, if you build a `Trie`, this could be reduced`O(m)` which is clearly better.

[Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/Trie.html) have some implementations, although if n is small here then I really won't bother and avoid adding complexity to my code and go with a simple loop.

Comment: You could go with a `HashMap` for O(1) retrieval.

Comment: @JamesBuck And how would you do prefix lookup in a HashMap?

Comment: It seems he only wants to map complete property names and not look up by partial prefixes.

Comment: @JamesBuck Where do you read that in the question? Properties is a HashTable btw and lookup by key is O(1)

Comment: @JamesBuck - I do not want want exact property names. Java properties already gives that. I want lookup by prefix. I am surprised actually that Java Properties does not have a built-in function for it

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Yes trie definitely seems to be the way to go. Even if there are 100s of values the optimization seems worth it.